# Why is my leader on fire?

Tags: the-wonderful-101

There are times when you may notice your team leader on fire. Maybe you took a hit while trying to lay on some heavy damage, or you had to dash to avoid said hit. What's that flame all about?  Does it hurt me?

Answer (score 3):

The flame around your party leader indicates that you can re-form your last Unite Morph. Let me explain:

All Unite Morphs have a certain duration, with larger Morphs lasting shorter than smaller ones. If it's forced to disassemble (for example, if an enemy blocks your attack and breaks it, or if you perform a dash) before it expires, however, you have a chance to renew it, indicated by a flaming aura around your team leader. As long as you have enough conscious party members, you can re-form the same Morph without having to draw a new Wonder-liner. Don't forget, though, that a Morph's time can still run down and expire even when you're not using it; watch for the flame to flash, as this indicates that the Morph is about to expire.